# How to get the active tab using selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I'm trying to identify how a new tab was active using Selenium.
After identifying, check if the url of this new tab contains any keyword.
And if this is possible without using the driver.switchto().Window(handle)?

Comment: What kind of research have you [conducted](http://www.crowbarsolutions.com/opening-and-closing-tabs-using-selenium/)?

Comment: `how a new tab was active using Selenium` - what do you mean? this makes no sense. And `if this is possible without using the driver.switchto().Window(handle)` - what is that supposed to mean? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to get the Title of the new tab opened?

if so,

each tab is considered as a window and initially store the list of windows using getWindowHandles() method which returns "Set" Collection(interface) as it doesn't allow duplicates.

Set allWindows=getWindowsHandles();

System.out.Println(allWindows.size());

Now, convert that into list interface.

```
List<String> listOfWindows=new ArrayList<String>
listOfWindows.add(allWindows);
```

if you require the title of second window then:

```
String secWindow=listOfWindows.get(1); 
System.out.Println(driver.getTitle());
driver.switchTo().window(secWindow);
```